# How can I display the NHibernate log4net SQL output on a web page?

Tags: performance, nhibernate, testing, log4net

I have NHibernate configured with log4net to output the SQL generated to the log file.

I am trying to figure out a way to display the SQL generated by NHibernate for a page request on the web page itself (mostly so that developers keep an eye on what's going on 'under the hood').

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware that NHibernate in logging-mode outputs heaps of data and info.

In log4net you can set the output message ourself in the config-file.

A suggestion is to change the output to html and present the logging-file with a webserver installed on the server.

Comment: Hey Helk, Thanks for the speedy response... My main goal is to get it showing on the page that the developer is working on, at the bottom of the page, vs a separate page.

Comment: Alright. Then you can try to save the output in a php file and then include this file on the main page and and show it on the bottom of the page

Comment: it doesnt have to be php btw. I guess you are working with c#?

Comment: yep C#. thanks for the idea. I think even just spitting out the last hundred lines or so of the log.txt file would do the trick.

Comment: this is my first post on stackoverflow, i love it!

Comment: Here's what I ended up doing: I added an optional switch in web.config. If the switch is on, there's some base page code to display last X lines of the log.txt on the bottom of the web page

Thanks Helk.